# memory error in python gridsearch

Tags: python, pandas, memory, dataframe, grid-search

i need to apply grid search i have  dataframe of 20000 columns and 110000 rows and i need to tune my parameters using grid search module of python

```
#validation for svm
#there are an error to check it ( grid search ne marche pas i will check why after)
label = df.Sentiment
train= df.drop('Sentiment', axis=1)


from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
text_clf = Pipeline([('tfidf', TfidfVectorizer()),
                      ('clf', LinearSVC()),
 ])
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
parameters = {'tfidf_min_df': [[0.8, 1.0], 1],
               'tfidf__max_df': ([0.8, 1.0], 1),
               'clf__c': (0.1, 1 , 10),
 }
gs_clf = GridSearchCV(text_clf, parameters)
gs_clf = gs_clf.fit(trainas_matrix(), label)
```

and i get this error

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- MemoryError                               Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>         3 classif = SklearnClassifier(LinearSVC())
>         4 # Séparation du set de train et de test
>   ----> 5 X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test = train_test_split(train.as_matrix(),label, test_size = 0.33)
>
> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/generic.pyc in
>   as_matrix(self, columns)    2832         self._consolidate_inplace()
>   2833         if self._AXIS_REVERSED:
>   -> 2834             return self._data.as_matrix(columns).T    2835         return self._data.as_matrix(columns)    2836
>
> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/internals.pyc in
>   as_matrix(self, items)    3148             return
>   mgr.blocks[0].get_values()    3149         else:
>   -> 3150             return mgr._interleave()    3151     3152     def _interleave(self):
>
> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/internals.pyc in
>   _interleave(self)    3157         dtype = _interleaved_dtype(self.blocks)    3158 
>   -> 3159         result = np.empty(self.shape, dtype=dtype)    3160     3161         if result.shape[0] == 0:
>
> MemoryError:

Comment: in `'tfidf_min_df'` you have forgotten an underscore. It should be `'tfidf__min_df'`. Also, what is trainas_matrix() ?